# Парсинг, Python, Почему выдает пустой класс?

Tags: python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему выдает пустой класс, пытаюсь спарсить наименование и код. Пишу так

```
def get_content(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find('div', class_='col-xs-12').find_all('div', class_='product-wrapper')
    # products = []
    # for item in items:
    #     products.append({
    #         'product_name': item.find('a', {'class': 'product-title'}).get_text(),
    #         'product_sklad': item.find('div', {'class': ['available','unavailable']}).get_text(),
    #         'product_code': item.find('div', class_='product-code').get_text(),
    #         'product_cost': item.find('div', class_='product-price').get_text()
    #     })

    print(items)
```

выдает пустоту. Подскажите где ошибаюсь?

```
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Возможно, оно JavaScript'ом генерируется

Comment: блин, а что делать, как спарсить тогда?

Comment: Думаю, что если бы Вы привели адрес сайта, то можно было бы и проверить все, а так... ну что поделать.

Comment: там сайт с авторизацией и персональные данные не мои, к сожалению не могу пароль дать, но сайт могу дать, вот он https://b2b.hpf.cz/

Answer (score 0):

Вы не должны передавать soap url ему нужен лишь тело ответа

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_content(context):
        print(context)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(context, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find('body').find_all('div')
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!\n",items)

url = "http://google.com"
req = requests.get(url)
get_content(req.content)
```

Так будет работать

Comment: в суп я передаю def get_html(url):
    resp = session.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    return resp  Я привел только ф-цию сбора данных

Comment: тогда откройте исходный код сайта и убедитесь что тело ответа действительно содержит требуемые div и классы  возможно этот контент собирается через api javascript В таком случае парсить еще легче используя direct link

Comment: также удостоверьтесь что парсер soap действительно разбирает сайт, бывают проблемы  html сломан

Comment: а что за direct link , ни разу не сталкивался, есть ссылка на инфу, где почитать?

Comment: суп то сайт разбирает, но class_='product-wrapper' не находит, т.е. не содержит получается. видать действительно через js .

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй открывать страницы через [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/), а вот потом уже используй BeautifulSoup.

Comment: попробую, только я еще с ним не парсил. щас почитаю доку

Comment: ты предлагаешь скомбинировать селениум и bs? а почему бы тогда просто не спарсить одним селениумом.. Так мне кажется уже будет проще.

Comment: У тебя была проблема с тем, что ты не можешь получить данные и умеешь работать с bs. Селениум подгрузит весь html, включая то, что генерит js динамически. А с помощью bs вытащишь, что надо. Если есть время, можешь подтянуть знания по селениум. Результат будет аналогичный, только затраты по времени больше.

Comment: дело в том, что я через селениум открываю вкладки, сохраняю страницу, для проверки, а в ней нет данных, точнее, например, вечером собрал данные, утром запуская код, уже нет данных, т.е. они не отображаются в сохраненной странице, хотя при открытии селениумом отображаются. Вот я и не пойму в чем дело. Кукисы я подгружаю перед заходом по ссылке. Что может быть?

Comment: Может быть я не так понимаю твое объяснение. Я правильно понимаю, что ты через селениум открываешь страницу, парсишь данные, потом сохраняешь страницу (Зачем? почему страницу, а не данные), а когда на следующий день пытаешься парсить данные с сохраненной страницы (зачем еще раз? ты уже получил данные вчера), то данных уже нет? Почему утром не открыть первоисточник через селениум и не спарсить снова, если тебе зачем-то это все таки надо?

Comment: Ты сравнивал, что отображает браузер, что показывает селениум и что ты сохраняешь? На каком этапе у тебя данные отваливаются?

Comment: Значит я открываю страницу селениумом, авторизуюсь, парсю данные, они нормально считались. закрываю. Утром запускаю этот же код, но данные уже не парсятся. В браузере через селениум теги с данными есть, отображаются, но когда для проверки сохраняю страницу, посмотреть есть ли теги, их нет. Вот и не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: Ты авторизуешься через селениум, передавая из скрипта логин и пароль? И на следующий день запуская парсер он не отрабатывает то. что делал первый день? А если в первый день несколько раз запустить парсер, он будет работать?

Comment: я его запустил раз, он отработал и я пошел спать со спокойной душой, но может если бы добил сразу несколько раз и вылезла ошибка, даже незнаю